# Covert strings inside for loop into a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list containing all the strings found inside double quotes, so far i've got to this.

```
matches = ['8 "app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php" line 1', '9 "app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php" line 1']

if len(matches) > 1:
    for match in matches:
        matches = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', match)
        print(matches[0])
```

It outputs this

```
app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php
app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php
```

I want to turn those strings into a list so it looks like this

```
['app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php','app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php']
```

It should also be dynamic as there can be more than 2 strings inside double quotes.

How can this be done?

Comment: I knew this was probably a typo, but I was really hoping that "covert strings" were things that acted like some other object, but under the covers they were really strings, waiting to be called upon to sneakily do stringy things in service of their homeland, and… I just described all of tkinter.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using `findall` to get all of the matches, but then throwing away all but the first?

Comment: It's a plugin for Sublime like Vim's buffer. The contents of the top matches is pulled in dynamically from the output panel which shows my open files, then when I open show_input_panel and type Http for example I want to store all matches so I can press tab to cycle through them and then press enter to take me to that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your `print` statement with an `append` to a list you initialized before the loop.

```
import re
matches = ['8 "app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php" line 1', '9 "app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php" line 1']

output = []
if len(matches) > 1:
    for match in matches:
        matches = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', match)
        output.append(matches[0])

print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
['app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php', 'app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate the list more succinctly.

In python, list comprehension allows for `[x for x in (1,4,3,2)] formatting.

So that would lead to this code.

```
import re
matches = ['8 "app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php" line 1', '9 "app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php" line 1']

results = [re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', match)[0] for match in matches]
```

The results variable will be:

`['app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php', 'app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php']`

Comment: Thanks for an alternate way of achieving this, I agree this is a much better way of doing it.